# Помогите написать тест на Python + Selenium + SQL server

Tags: python, sql-server

Использовать Python + Selenium + SQL server

Открыть стaрничку гугл, вписать новости, выбрать два сайта, скопировать определенный текст и самое непонятное для меня, занести текст в базу данных MySQL. До момента занести в базу данных текст, все знаю, а как занести, не знаю, дайте пример кода, если кто-то знает

Вот мой код с базой данных, пытаюсь вытянуть хотя бы для начала пару строк с таблицы northwind:

```
import pypyodbc
my_sql_server = 'LAPTOP-Q5MJ2UNM'
my_database = 'Northwind'
connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver = {SQL Server};'
                              'Server =' + my_sql_server + ';'
                              'Database =' + my_database + ';')

cursor = connection.cursor()
mySQLQuery = ("""
SELECT CompanyName, ContactName, country
FROM dbo.Customers
WHERE country = 'USQ'   

"""
)
cursor.execute(mySQLQuery)
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)
connection.close()
```

Вот такую ошибку имею:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/eeNNdd11/PycharmProjects/course python/Selenium/Database SQL.py", line 9, in <module>
    'Database =' + my_database + ';')
  File "D:\Python1\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 2454, in __init__
    self.connect(connectString, autocommit, ansi, timeout, unicode_results, readonly)
  File "D:\Python1\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 2507, in connect
    check_success(self, ret)
  File "D:\Python1\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1009, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, ODBC_obj.dbc_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
  File "D:\Python1\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 985, in ctrl_err
    raise Error(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Источник данных не найден и не указан драйвер, используемый по умолчанию')
```

Comment: Создать базу из MySQL клиента, поставить в Python модуль работы с MySQL базами, установить соединение с базой, выполнить запросы `INSERT INTO`, отсоединиться от базы. Не понимаю, сложно вбить в поисковике "Python MySQL пример" или что-то в этом роде?!

Comment: Поставил сервер, закинул базу Northwind, хочу вытянуть от туда пару столбцов,  синтаксически, код правильный, но выбивает ошибку:                                    
pypyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Источник данных не найден и не указан драйвер, используемый по умолчанию')

Comment: Правильной дорогой идёте, товарищ! А теперь вставьте, пожалуйста, Ваш код работы с базой в вопрос. А мы посмотрим и подскажем, что не так. И, кстати, Вы работаете не с MySQL, а с SQL Server. Но это не столь важно. Отличаются, в основном, только строки команды соединения с базой.

Comment: @SergeyNudnov Вот собственно код с базой данных, пытаюсь самое простое сделать, но какой-то драйвер не указан, гуглил, но ответа не нашел, может вы подскажите?!

Comment: @VyacheslavBondarev, под другим вопросом я уже вам написал, что возможно проблема в том, что вы не указываете имя и пароль пользователя при подключении. Вы проверяли этот вариант?

Comment: да, уже проверил, дело было в том, что грамматически неправильно указал имя ODBC драйвер) А имя, пароль, не указывал, когда ставил SQL.

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, отметьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый нажатием на `v` под счётчиком голосов.

Answer (score 3):

В Вашем коде - следующие проблемы:

- использован модуль pypyodbc.

  Последний раз код pypyodbc изменяли два года назад. Он имеет 140
  звёзд на GitHub'е.

  Советую использовать [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc). 1304 звезды на GitHub, ведётся разработка и сопровождение.
- В строке соединения не допускаются пробелы. Она должна иметь следующий формат:

  `DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=test;DATABASE=test;UID=user;PWD=password`

Несколько вещей, которые нужно иметь в виду:

- Имя драйвера в `{}` должно точно совпадать с именем, указанным в ODBC Data Source Administrator. Причем для Python 32-bit нужно смотреть 32-bit версию администратора, а для Python 64-bit - 64-битную.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Имя или IP адрес сервера часто полезно сопровождать портом:

  `SERVER=test-server,1433;`
- Можно подключаться к SQL Server, используя Ваш Windows логин. Вместо логина и пароля, добавьте:

  `Trusted_Connection=yes;`

Дополнительная информация по pyodbc и SQL Server - [здесь](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows).

P.S. Я не проверял, но очень возможно, что и регистр имен параметров в строке соединения тоже важен. Так что лучше уж пишите их заглавными буквами. Если получится и со строчными - дайте знать :)

Comment: Пробелы и регистр я протестирую. `Имя или IP адрес сервера часто полезно сопровождать портом` - не очень полезно, нужно только если для экземпляра SQL Server нестандартный порт (не 1433). Про подключение со своим Windows логином - будет работать только если пользователь добавлен в пользователях экземпляра SQL Server.

Comment: @insolor `Имя или IP адрес сервера часто полезно сопровождать портом` - Вы таки будете не верить, но это потом и кровью выстраданное утверждение. В enterprise, когда сервер базы зафайрволен по самое немогу, динамический поиск часто не срабатывает. Мне некогда было копать глубоко, чего ему не хватает. Добавление порта - решает проблему. Насчёт Windows логина - разумеется, пользователь должен быть добавлен. Все нюансы не разжуешь...

Answer (score 1):

Тестировал на pyodbc, драйвер ODBC - SQL Server, версия 6.01.7601.17514, MS SQL Server 2014.

1. Пробелы имеют значение, из-за лишних пробелов как раз выходит ошибка `[IM002] [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Источник данных не найден и не указан драйвер, используемый по умолчанию (0) (SQLDriverConnect)`.
2. Если лишние пробелы убрать, но не указать имя входа и пароль, будет ошибка `[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Не удалось выполнить вход. Имя входа принадлежит недоверенному домену и не может использоваться в проверке подлинности Windows. (18452) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Не удалось выполнить вход. Имя входа принадлежит недоверенному домену и не может использоваться в проверке подлинности Windows. (18452)'`

Пример рабочих настроек:

```
my_sql_server = 'LAPTOP-Q5MJ2UNM'
my_database = 'Northwind'
name = 'sa'  # меняете на свое имя входа SQL
password = '...'  # и пароль

connection = pyodbc.connect(
    'Driver={{SQL Server}};'
    'Server={server};'
    'Database={database};'
    'UID={username};'
    'PWD={password};'
    .format(server=my_sql_server, database=my_database, username=name, password=password))
```

Двойные фигурные скобки вокруг `SQL Server` нужны чтобы правильно работал метод `format` (после применения метода `format` двойные фигурные скобки превратятся в одинарные).